# How to pass local shell script variable to expect?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

My question is related to [How to pass variables from a shell script to an expect script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422757/how-to-pass-variables-from-shell-script-to-expect-script)

but its slightly different:

Apart from passing two runtime shell script variables, I want to pass a variable thats inside the shell script For eg:

```
#!/bin/sh
d=`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M'`

expect -c '
expect "sftp>"


#use $d here(how?)
'
```

Comment: `expect -c ' .... '"$d"'......'` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pass a date variable into expect. It has a very good date command builtin:

```
expect -c '

# ...

set d [timestamp -format "%Y%m%d_%H%M"]
something_with $d

# ...
'
```

If you need to do more complicated date manipulation, read about the Tcl [clock](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm) command

---

Another good technique to pass shell variables to expect (without having to do complicated/messy quoting/escaping) is to use the environment: export your shell variables, and then access them with expect's global `env` array:

```
export d=$(date ...)

expect -c 'puts "the date is $env(d)"'
```

Comment: In this case I'm building another date. I want to use the date that the shell script generated..

Answer (score 2):

This seems the wrong way to do things. You should set up SSH keys (with ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id), google about this.

Anyway, try this :

```
#!/bin/sh
d=`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M'`

expect -c "

something_with $d"
```

Note the double quotes instead of single quotes.

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: "$var", "$(command "$var")", "${array[@]}", "a & b". Use 'single quotes' for code or literal $'s: 'Costs $5 US', ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes , http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: note: I already have double quotes several times inside the expect block

Comment: You can replace nested `"` by `\042`

Comment: Maybe there's better solutions, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I'm using the local shell variable $d inside this script directly and running it now. I'll post in the next few mins when it completes.

Comment: This seems the wrong way to do things. You should set up SSH keys (with ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id), google about this.