# How to pass variable to the expect file in bash?

Tags: bash, expect

I have read this post:
[How to pass local shell script variable to expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389113/how-to-pass-local-shell-script-variable-to-expect)

But my expect script is a single file, not like his.

I have a expect script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

send "echo 'hello' \n"

exit 0
```

I also have a bash script file:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="Neil"
b="Thunel"

expect ./test01.exp 

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo "success！"
else
    echo "fail！"
fi
```

I want to pass `$a` and `$b` to the expect file, but I don't know how to do with that.

Comment: ```expect -c "My expect commands are using $a and $b variables"``` (notice the double quotes)

Comment: Thank you, my expect file is a single file. and now through the duplicate link I have solved my issue.